# How can I save the first line of a file?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to save the first line of a file using python, but all the time it ends up deleting the first lines and scrolling over the top.

```
newfile = open('news.php', 'r+');
newfile.write('Texto');
newfile.close();
```

Comment: Where are you reading the file?  And where do you want to save it to?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add to the top of the file (pushing the top line down):

```
with open("news.php", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# insert the desired top line at index 0, either directly or with a variable
content.insert(0, some_new_first_line)

with open("news.php", "w") as f:
    content = "".join(content)
    f.write(content)
```